# The total number of edges given a adjacency matrix

Tags: matlab, graph, edges

I need to calculate the total number of edges given the adjacency matrix for a undirected simple graph. I was told that I could perform this in MATLAB using the following:

```
n_edges=sum(sum(Adj))/2;
```

Can someone explain how it is calculating the edges?

Comment: `Adj(i,j) = 1` tells you there is an edge connecting nodes `i` and `j`. If `A(i,j) = 1` then `A(j,i) = 1` as well, as these indicate the same edge. Since we count every edge twice, we need to divide the total by 2.

Comment: @eigenchris - You should consider making your comment an answer because it pretty much solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just repeating my comment...

`Adj(i,j) = 1` tells you there is an edge connecting nodes `i` and `j`. If `A(i,j) = 1` then `A(j,i) = 1` as well, as these indicate the same edge. Since we count every edge twice, we need to divide the total by 2.